# Convert each row of pandas DataFrame to a separate Json string

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, pandas

I use this code in order to convert each row of pandas DataFrame `df` into Json string. The problem is that it's printing `None`, however `df.head()` prints out the data.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_csv('mydataset.csv')

for i in df.index:
    print df.loc[i].to_json("row{}.json".format(i))
    if i==10:
        break
```

How to get each row as a Json string variable and print it out? The Json string's structure is plain, no arrays, just string, integer and float fields.

Comment: @ScottBoston: The question is how to convert each row to json string, because my code does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with parameter `axis=1` for process by rows:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.to_json("row{}.json".format(x.name)), axis=1)
```

If want only see output:

```
df.apply(lambda x: print(x.to_json()), axis=1)
```

EDIT:

Use custom function:

```
def f(x):
    a = x.to_json()
    print (a)


df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: I want to convert each row within the for loop, because `df` is large and also because I need to make some processing within the for loop.

Comment: if I do `for row in df.iterrows():
    data = row.to_json()`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Just one small issue. Empty data is converted to `"field1":null`. is there any way to convert all empty strings to `""`?

Comment: Yes, need `df.fillna("").apply(f, axis=1)`

Comment: But can I apply it to each row? For example: `jsonstring = df.iloc[i].to_json()`, and then what I should do with `jsonstring`?

Answer (score 3):

`.to_json(fname)` function will write the data to a json file directly and will not return anything to you, so the print will return you none, but the actual files are there in your file system.

---

Update: if you want to save the json string as a variable in python, then don't specify the filename argument in the function `to_json()`. You can do: `a = df.iloc[0].to_json()` and the string will be saved to variable `a`.

Comment: So, then how can I get this Json string into a variable? In this case I want to substitute `to_json`.

Comment: @Dinosaurius If you don't specify a file name argument in the `to_json()` function, you can save it as a variable in python.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't happy with the solutions presented and ended up doing this:

```
for chunk in (pd.read_csv(file, sep = ",", header = False, index_col = 0, chunksize=chunk_size)):
    json_chunk = chunk.to_json(orient = "records", force_ascii = True, default_handler = None)
```

My solution does it with chunks as I'm reading millions of rows.

Comment: Oh Man!! You have saved so many manual efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this worked for me to have the last column saved as JSon using this:

```
df.assign(ln_A = lambda x: x.to_json()))
```

Answer (score 0):

to produce a json record for each dataframe:

```
for i in df.index:
    record = df.iloc[i].to_json()
    print(record)
```